# filter based on time range in each group sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a table that stores all the purchases from a known number of customers. So each row contains the name of the customer and an item that is bought and the time of the purchase.

We can actually find the first purchase made by each customer.

I want to order the rows based on time of purchase for each customer but having a condition that time of purchase should be from at least 2 months from the first purchase of that customer.

Let's illustrate that more in an example:
(Purchases in each customer sorted by time)

```
customer1 purchases: 2018/7/1 , 2018/8/2, 2018/9/3, 2019,9,4
customer2 purchases: 2019/10/10 , 2019/10/11, 2019/10/12, 2019,11,11
...
```

For customer 1, if we want to find the orders from 2 months from the older purchase( i.e `2018/7/1`), we get `2018/9/3, 2019,9,4`

For customer 2, the oldest purchase is `2018/7/1`, so we get `2019,11,11`

**Basically for each customer, I want to find all the purchases that are at least 2 months after the oldest purchase sorted by time.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you only want the dates of the purchases, you can use an aggregation to get them in lists already. In Postgresql, this would be something like:

```
SELECT customer_id, ARRAY_AGG(date ORDER BY date)
FROM purchase
JOIN (
    SELECT customer_id, min(date) as date
    FROM purchases
    GROUP BY customer_id
) AS first_purchase ON first_purchase.customer_id = purchase.customer_id
WHERE purchase.date >= first_purchase.date + '2 MONTHS'::interval
GROUP BY customer_id
```

And in SQLAlchemy:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import aggregate_order_by

first_purchase = sa.select([
  Purchase.customer_id,
  sa.func.max(Purchase.date).label('date')
]).group_by(Purchase.customer_id).subquery()

query = sa.select([
  Purchase.customer_id,
  sa.func.array_agg(aggregate_order_by(Purchase.date, Purchase.date))
]).select_from(
  Purchase.join(first_purchase,
                first_purchase.c.customer_id == Purchase.customer_id)
).where(
  Purchase.date >= first_purchase.c.date + sa.cast('2 MONTHS', sa.Interval)
).group_by(Purchase.customer_id)
```

Note how similar the structure of both queries is